# criação de gif no r

Tags: r, animação

Estou tentando crias um GIF do plot abaixo:

```
x<-NULL
y<-NULL
for(i in 1:500){
  y[i]<-sum(rnorm(i))/i
  x[i]<-i
  plot(y~x, type="l")
  abline(y=0)
  Sys.sleep(0.25)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Há diversas maneiras de produzir um gif no R. Se quiser fazer a transformação das imagens em gif direto no seu computador, você vai precisar de [imageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Mostro aqui um exemplo utilizando o pacote [`magick`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/magick.pdf) e as funções `image_graph()` para salvar cada gráfico em um objeto, `image_animate()` para a animação e `image_write()` para salvar o gif.

Salvando o plot de cada interação com a função `image_graph()`:

```
    library(magick)

    # atenção que pode demorar alguns minutos
    x<-1
    y<-1
    for(i in 1:250){
      y[i]<-sum(rnorm(i))/i
      x[i]<-i
        name <- paste0('fig', i)
        assign(name, image_graph(res = 65))
        plot(y~x, type="l")
        dev.off()
    }
```

Agora que cada plot esta salvo em um objeto diferente (`figi`), podemos juntar todos em um vetor:

```
    # vetor de nomes
    figs <- paste0('fig', 1:250)

    # unindo os plots
    img <- mget(figs)
    img <- image_join(img)
```

Criando e salvando o gif:

```
    gif <- image_animate(img, fps = 10, dispose = "previous")

    image_write(gif, "gif.gif")
```

Referencia para mais funcionalidades do pacote `magick` podem ser encontradas [aqui](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html).

**EDIT**:

Dependendo da quantidade e complexidade das figuras criadas, é importante lembrar da memória disponível:

```
# remover todos os plots da memória
rm(list = ls()[ls() %in% paste0('fig', 1:250)])
```

Comment: Obrigado @willian . Mas: `Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) : 
  Magick: unable to extend cache '#FFFFFFFFFFFF': Não há espaço disponível no dispositivo @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3883`

Comment: Provavelmente um problema de memória devido à arquivos muito grande. Uma opções é diminuir o número de gráficos para transformar em gif ou reduzir a qualidade do gráfico (com o `res`). Além disso, você pode ver se é algum bug no seu código. Você pode tentar debugar indo etapa por etapa e medindo o tamanho dos objetos com a funcção `object.size()`.